# How to add link style for <a> in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

The code is very simple:

```
<a>This is a link</a>
```

In Bootstrap 4 Alpha 2 [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/svwg63rs/1/), the link shows blue. When you hover mouse on it, it shows dark blue.

But in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3 [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/Ly3s7q1a/), it shows black.

Is there any special Bootstrap class can be added to let `<a>` have link style in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3?

Something like this?

```
<a class="bootstrap-link">This is a link</a>
```

Is there any clean/smart way?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably something changed between the two versions regarding the existence of the `href` attribute; by adding the attribute `href` to the anchor `<a>`, it starts to work properly;

Code from the example with href:

`<a href>This is a link</a>`

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s1mvqok0/

Comment: If you want a link to do nothing, you could use `javascript:void()` as the `href` content. Theoretically, every anchor should point to somewhere though, otherwise, some other tag should be used.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. I will leave this open, hope there is a clean way in alpha 3

Comment: @HongboMiao __ you should mark this answer as accepted since it answers your question. An anchor that is a link should have an href.

Comment: @PedroMoreira 's `href="javascript:void()"` works nicely in BS4Beta to apply a consistent link style to a `<a class="dropdown-toggle">`.  This works better for certain themes where `text-primary` won't work because it does not match link color.

Comment: If you use `<a class="btn">...</a>` this bootstrap behaviour can be annoying. Remember you can also use `<button class="btn">...</button>` https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19402#issuecomment-247377640

Comment: In Angular 11 this solution casuses the page to reload...

Answer (score 3):

If you see bootstrap 4 css

```
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So anchor tag gets the color of its parent element if it does not have either an href or tabindex attribute. One approach would be to provide a tabindex for the a element.

There is a class if you want to use `.text-primary` that applies primary color to the anchor tag.

```
.text-primary{
   color:#0275d8!important
}
a.text-primary:focus,a.text-primary:hover{
   color:#025aa5
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly3s7q1a/1/)

Comment: Hi, this is a much neat way! But right now it does not show correct style when you hover the mouse on the link.

Comment: This might be what is recommended for standards, but until they come up with an href attribute for `button` elements, people are gonna be using anchors for buttons.  This rule could be greatly improved by adding `:not([role="button"])` or something like that.  The solution you put is okay but it poses an annoyance for outlined buttons - there is no simple fix there